# SQL Server Configuration manager not found anywhere on the drive

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-config-manager

I want to enable TCP/IP on my SQL Server Express 2016 but I cannot find SQL Server Configuration Manager. I am using windows 10 and I couldn't find it in the start menu and I can't find it by searching for SQLServerManager13.msc in this pc. I tried all the things I found on google but I still can't find it. I have installed sql in visual studio and installed sql server configuration manager seperately. How to find it?

Also, I'm new to sql.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes, but I still can't find it. Is it because I have installed it in visual studio?

Comment: Did you read the big purple Note that tells you *exactly* what to do?

Comment: Even if I type SQLServerManager13.msc in start, it just tells me that it wasn't found.

Comment: That would suggest you have not installed SQL Server like you said you have, @Jurij15 .

Comment: @Larnu I will try reinstalling it.

Comment: I had the same problem, as near as I can tell, it is not installed by default for certain versions and editions (like Express and Developer) of SQL Server. No idea why, nor why they made it exclusively an MMC applet